# Does SSH keys stores host informations?

Tags: ssh, rsa

I was wondering if SSH keys stores the host information or if it's possible by any way?

As far as I know RSA or ED25519 keys doesn't stores the host information and researches doesn't gave me any more clues about if it's possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no:

Plain SSH keys have a "comment" field which usually stores the username of the person who generated the key, as well as the hostname where that key was generated. The comment field is not used for security checks, and does not "bind" a key to a specific host. The keys do not store any other host-specific information besides that.

OpenSSH *certificates* work similarly to TLS certificates, and actually store a list of names that they're valid for. Host certificates (ssh_host_rsa_key-cert.pub) store a list of hostnames; user certificates (id_rsa-cert.pub) store a list of usernames.

Comment: AFAIR only public keys contain comments, private ones don't.

Comment: So we could use certificates that have an host stored inside to connect to SSH servers?

Comment: @gronostaj: PuTTY .ppk and OpenSSH new 'bcrypt' format keys do store comments, only PEM keys don't.

Comment: @NathanaelDemacon: Do you mean giving a user a certificate that only allows connection to specific hosts?

Comment: Yup! It's possible to store certificates so it might be possible

Comment: No, that won't work. Certificates only store identity, not access rights – e.g. user certificates only store the _user_ names that the user can log in as. (Similarly, host certificates store hostnames because they are presented _by_ the host, very much like HTTPS certificates.) I think there was a thread on openssh-unix-dev about this just a month ago, and the general consensus seemed to be that server-side access configuration is more apropriate for that.

Comment: (It is possible to add custom attributes to OpenSSH certificates, which might include a list of hosts in a user certificate, but you'd need to customize the server to actually pay attention to those first...)